# Android PushUp Notification on data change

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, mariadb

If for example an user comments another users post, what is the best way to notify the user that there is a new comment? The data is stored in a MariaDB database and the backend is NodeJS. I already tried it to do with Google Firebase, but I do not know how to implement the check if there is a new comment on the users post.

Comment: There are two steps to the problem: 1) finding which users have new comments, 2) sending a notification to those users. Since you're struggling with step 1, I'd recommend limiting your question to that. Edit your question to include your database schema (what relevant tables and columns you have) and the SQL you've already tried. If you include these, and remove anything not relevant to that minimal problem, it's much more likely that someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should manage the Firebase token at your server level. You can update device token on server while user is login into your app.
Now once new comment is made by any user, you will know the creator of that post. fetch the Firebase token from your DB , prepare a Data Notification payload and send request to Firebase server, Firebase server will send your payload to your client (Creator of that post).
At application level onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) method will called. Now you can get the payload from remoteMessage object and can push  notification on Notification Channel.

For Firebase Integration in android you can follow quick start sample https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

To send request from your application server to Firebase you can use Firebase Rest API following is example in your use case.

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA
{"data":
{"user_profile_thumbnail":"profile thumbnail of user who comment to show on
 notification","post_id":"System generated post
id","user_name":"Name of user","comment_id":"system generated comment 
id","user":"commented user key(may be primary key to identify 
user"},"to":"post_creator_FCM_Token"
}
```

For more details you can look at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message